# How do you say “Cluster Fucks” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm working on a novelty team/group name for my University game design course. We all agreed on the name 'Cluster Fucks' but they said we cannot use it. We can, however, use it in an alternate language.

Does anyone know how to say 'Cluster fucks' or 'Group of Fucks' or 'Team of Fucks' or something in Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain what you want to mean by the phrase? Different languages rarely have exact equivalents, so what we need for a translation is not just the words but **the idea that you want to convey**. Context and nuance make a huge difference. Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific answer you seek, but "clusterfucks" is a hilarious name for a group.

Comment: Downvote because the title is vague

Answer (score 4):

In Latin a cluster may be species-specific, like collective-nouns, in English e.g. "racemus" = "bunch, or cluster, of grapes or other fruit"; or, "corymbus" = "cluster of ivy-berries or flowers or fruit". A cluster (group of people) may require e.g. "manus" = "band" of (usually soldiers [a military force of any size]; of workmen; of relatives). It can also mean "the legal power of a husband"--interesting, though, perhaps irrelevant, to this.).

Verb, "futuo" = "to have sexual relations (with a woman)"; third-person singular, "futuit", giving:

> "manus futuit" = "the cluster (group) fucks".

Comment: But of course manus primarily means "hand".  I don't really think this is what the question requires.

Comment: The English term is (usually) a compound noun, not a noun+verb combination.

Comment: @fdb: Noun, "manus", has a number of meanings of which "hand" is but one. In English "hand" has a group-connotation e.g. "The Black Hand", which had more than one member. This understanding appears to hold in Latin: "manus" = "a hand" &  "a band". Further, well-used in military matters e.g. "exigua manus" = "a small force":  the noun has a group-identity, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @rjpond: Given such circumstances, I've tried an alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

Like fdb, I assume you mean this (from *Oxford English Dictionary*):

> Originally *Military*. A bungled or botched undertaking; (also) a situation, state of affairs, or gathering (esp. a military operation) that is disorganized or chaotic.

Not this (*ibid.*):

> A sexual orgy.

If, so, I'm highly doubtful that the Latin equivalent (at least the classical Latin equivalent) would be based on the same metaphor as the English. Instead, I tend to think that it would be something more scatological. Seneca the Younger, *Apocolocyntosis* 4.3 points toward a possible alternative:

> *ultima vox eius haec inter homines audita est, cum maiorem sonitum emisisset illa parte, qua facilius loquebatur: 'vae me, puto, concacavi me.' quod an fecerit, nescio; **omnia certe concacavit**.*

Translation by P.T. Eden:

> This was the last utterance of his to be heard in this world, after he had let out a louder sound from that part by which he found it easier to communicate: 'Oh dear, I think I've shit myself.' I rather suspect he did. **He certainly shat up everything else.**

The verb *concacare* (literally, 'To make foul with ordure, soil') doesn't have any derivatives, at least in classical Latin, but it's easy enough to use one of the standard suffixes that are added to verb roots to express the act or result of those verbs – for example, *concacamentum* (plural *concacamenta*) or *concacimonium* (plural *concacimonia*).

Furthermore, since a clusterfuck differs from a regular fuck-up in intensity and/or scale, you might add an adjective such as *maximus* ('the greatest, very great') or even *merus* ('nothing short of, pure, sheer, absolute, out-and-out'), and so render 'the clusterfucks' as *maxima* [or *mera*] *concacamenta* [or *concacimonia*]. (Note that no word for 'the' is needed in Latin.)

Alternatively, you could use a participle of the same verb, as in Petronius, *Satyricon* 66.7:

> *in summo habuimus caseum mollem ex sapa et cocleas singulas et cordae frusta et hepatia in catillis et ova pilleata et rapam et senape et **catillum concacatum**, pax Palamedes.*

Translation by P.T. M. Heseltine and W.H.D. Rouse (revised by E.H. Warmington):

> To finish up with we had cheese mellowed in new wine, and snails all round, and pieces of tripe, and liver in little dishes, and eggs in caps, and turnip, and mustard, and **a mucked up dish** – but hold hard, Palamedes.

This could yield something like *res maxime concacatae*, 'things very greatly shat up.'

Answer (score 2):

As I do not know this term I have looked it up in (where else?) the "urban dictionary" site, which informs me that "cluster fuck" means:

> "1) a bad situation that involves many different smaller situations to
> create one massive insanely intense ordeal. 2) when to (sic) many
> things happen at once, making it extremely hard to comprehend."

Presumably this is what you have in mind. You cannot really translate it literally, but you could try to capture the spirit of it with an ad-hoc compound like multifututio. Fututio “an act of coition” is excellent classical Latin, attested in Catullus.